# Cannot push new branch with same name as a deleted branch to create a branch on the remote repository

Tags: git, push, bitbucket-server, sourcetree

Ok the title is pretty confusing but heres what happened:

-Had a local branch with its corresponding remote branch

-Deleted both branches

-Recreated branch with same name, and applied my changes

-Cannot push to remote repository because:

```
'Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details."
```

Comment: What commands did you use to execute your 'deleted both branches' step?

Answer (score 3):

You didn't actually delete the remote branch, you deleted the local branch (`git branch -d`), and probably the local reference to the remote branch (`git branch -d -r`).

To delete a remote branch you need to `push` a null reference to the remote: `git push REMOTE_NAME :REMOTE_BRANCH_NAME`. The space before the colon is the null reference that tells `REMOTE_NAME` to delete branch `REMOTE_BRANCH_NAME`.

Now if you thought you'd deleted the remote branch and your intention is just to delete it and then push up your new branch you could save yourself a step and just do a force push: `git push -f` which will have the same effect.